# LFTP exclude file extensions

Tags: linux, centos, regular-expression, lftp

I am trying to mirror directories with lftp but I don't want to download filetypes that are notoriously large like .mp4 and .swf. But I am having trouble with the regex - and seeming like the exclude-glob too. Both of them download all files.

What I tried:

`/usr/local/bin/lftp -u user,pass  -e 'mirror -x ^(\.mp4|\.swf)$ $src $dest' ftp.host`

&&

`/usr/local/bin/lftp -u user,pass -e 'mirror -X swf $src $dest' ftp.host`

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you have to quote the vertical bar (|), since inside lftp it is a special symbol too (also use double quotes to interpolate src and dest variables, quote backslash and dollar sign to prevent their interpretation by the shell):

```
/usr/local/bin/lftp -u user,pass -e "mirror -x '^(\\.mp4|\\.swf)\$' $src $dest" ftp.host
```

In the second case you have to use glob patterns, like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/lftp -u user,pass -e "mirror -X *.mp4 -X *.swf $src $dest" ftp.host
```

In any case I would recommend to test the mirror command by hand first and automate it later.